# firebase firestore Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.delete@firestore.googleapis.co

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Since yesterday, I was unable to deploy a firebase cloud functions based on firestore event, I got the following error

`Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.delete@firestore.googleapis.com (removePropertyFromIndex)`

my console output from firebase deploy

[image]

I created two empty function with firestore event but same issue :

⚠  functions[test1]: Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (test1)
⚠  functions[test2]: Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (test2)

```
    exports.test1 = functions.firestore
      .document('programs/{programKey}')
      .onCreate(async event => {});

    exports.test2 = functions.firestore
      .document('programs/123')
      .onCreate(async event => {});
```

Comment: I have the same error when trying to deploy a trigger. Worked fine yesterday...

Comment: Same issue. I guess it's a bug? Both Firebase Cloud Functions and Cloud Firestore are beta products. Maybe related to https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17025

Comment: I have the same issue too, I deployed to a new project and the functions are working fine. But in the original project, they are not updating or removing. Tried both removing all functions from index.js then deploying and also via the console.

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: Can you share how you declared the function?

Comment: checking the google cloud console, it says the Trigger type is "unknown"...

Comment: The functions can't be deleted either through the google cloud console. It displays the same error in the logs:
`Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update@firestore.googleapis.com (functionName)`

Comment: This error might have been caused by a temporary issue affecting Cloud Functions between 2017-10-19 12:30 and 2017-10-20 15:30 US/Pacific Time. It is of interest to know if this still happens right now, after the incident has been closed, so Cloud Functions are supposed to work as expected.

Comment: yes it works since the accident was closed