# Firestore Cloud write functions not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a chain of promises that are triggered when a stripe payment is done. My functions properly lint and compile but they are not deployed but when i try the `firebase deploy --only functions` i get this error

```
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (37.79 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function stripeCharge(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function getTime(us-central1)...
+  functions[getTime(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
!  functions[stripeCharge(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com 
(__gcf__.us-central1.stripeCharge)


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as 
database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Here is my code for my function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const stripe = require('stripe')('mytestkey');

exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
   .document('/store{userId}/mypayments/activepayments/{paymentId}')
   .onCreate((snap, event) => {
     const payment = snap.data()
     const userId = event.params.userId
     const paymentId = event.params.paymentId
     console.log(payment);

   // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
   if (!payment || payment.charge) return null;

   return admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
       return snapshot
      })
      .then(snapshot => {
        const amount = payment.amount // amount must be in cents
        const idempotency_key = paymentId  // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.source.id;
        const currency = 'usd'
        const charge = { amount, currency, source }
        console.log(charge);

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key })
      })
      .then((charge) => {
        admin.firestore()
          .doc(`store${userId}/mypayments/activepayments/${paymentId}`)
          .set({
            charge: charge 
          }, { merge: true })
          .then(() => {
            if (charge.status === 'succeeded') {
              if (payment.amount === 3000) {
                const validTill = Date.now() + 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                admin.firestore()
                  .doc(`/store${userId}/stats/mystatistics/exp`)
                  .set({
                    validTill
                  }).then(() => {
                    console.log('successfully updated expiration date from server');
                  }
                  )
                  .catch(er => {
                    console.log(er);
                     return er;
                   })
               }
              if (payment.amount === 2000) {
                const validTill = Date.now() + 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                admin.firestore()
                  .doc(`/store${userId}/stats/mystatistics/exp`)
                  .set({
                    exp: validTill
                  },{merge: false})
                  .catch(er => {
                    console.log(er);
                    return er;
                 })
              }
             if (payment.amount === 5100) {
                const validTill = Date.now() + 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                admin.firestore()
                   .doc(`/store${userId}/stats/mystatistics/exp`)
                   .set({
                   exp: validTill
                  },{merge: false})
                   .catch(er => {
                    return er;
                  })
              }
               if (payment.amount === 2700) {
               const validTill = Date.now() + 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                admin.firestore()
                  .doc(`/store${userId}/stats/mystatistics/exp`)
                  .set({
                    exp: validTill
                   },{merge: false})
                  .catch(er => {
                    return er;
                  })
              }  
              if (payment.amount === 500) {
                const validTill = Date.now() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                admin.firestore()
                 .doc(`/store${userId}/stats/mystatistics/exp`)
                 .set({
                    exp: validTill
                  },{merge: false})
                  .catch(er => {
                    return er;
                  })
               }
            }
           }).catch(er =>{
             console.log(er)
         })
       })
      .catch(er=>{
         console.log(er);
      })
  })
```

I would really appreciate any help figuring out where the problem is coming from and why my triggers are not being saved

Comment: Not 100% sure... but I'm suspicious of the `/store{userId}/mypayments` part of your trigger. I can't remember ever seeing any triggers that use a "partial" wildcard like that, and a quick google search didn't turn anything up. Where did you learn that `/store{userId}/` was okay? I've only ever see the whole portion of the route wildcard'ed: `/{storeuserId}/`... try wildcarding the whole thing `/{storeuserId}/`

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844224/trying-to-deploy-firebase-functions-deploy-error-failed-to-configure-trigger 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040239/4712391

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843760/firebase-firestore-deploy-error-failed-to-configure-trigger-providers-cloud-fir?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I put it like that because I'm trying to save the users payment history under his database. And I saved each user in the database like that e.g(store15hskav456gakbfyql/mypayments/activepayments/gavfjdn2495gagfk) would be a path

Comment: @user10112707 Right, I see what you're trying to do, I've just never seen it done that way. Did you get that from somewhere, or did you make that up on your own? If you made it up, then I bet that's your breaking point... try making the whole thing a wildcard and see if it will deploy correctly.

Comment: @JeremyW's finding seems spot on, I doubt partial segments are supported. Try with a regular path `.document('/store/{userId}/mypayments/activepayments/{paymentId}')`. If that deploys (it won't work of course), you know what caused the problem. Btw Jeremy: I'd probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Consider rewriting your code using async/await, will increase the readability a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my (*and others*) comments above, the consensus is that the route you are watching as the trigger is not valid - I don't think Firebase supports "*partial*" wildcards like `/store{userId}/`... I get what you're trying to do, I just don't think it's supported.

Try altering your trigger to watch

```
.document('/{storeUserId}/mypayments/activepayments/{paymentId}')
```

and that should deploy. You'll have to change the way you plan on storing information, but the trigger will work.

Comment: You were right. Partial Wildcards ARE NOT supported by firebase i fixed this issue by increasing the path like
`.document('users/{userId}/{storeuserId}/mypayments/activepayments/{paymentId}')` So i could get the userId from somewhere else and still have the store Id from a different location. Really grateful for the help